# Foundations and Fundamental Concepts of Mathematics, Chapter Problems (1.1.3)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

student here on break exploring a math via a book called **Foundations and Fundamental Concepts of Mathematics.**

I'm pretty new to stack overflow and am not very familiar with etiquette or protocol. I have been reprimanded already. I apologize in advance if I have violated either.

Note: I do not want the solution, rather, a hint or a point to a false assumption I've made.

---

1.1.3 *Show that the ancient Babylonian formula K = (**a** + **c**)(**b** + **d**)/4, for the area of a quadrilateral having **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d** for consecutive sides, gives too large an answer for all non rectangular quadrilaterals.*

So, my course of action was to show that K is larger than the correct Area formulas for the list of all non-rectangular quadrilaterals:

I was able to show (easily, I think...) for (2) and (3). I had difficulty with (1), and I believe my brain is farting and I've made an assumption I haven't yet realized is wrong or am blind to something.

---

1. Kite/Rhombus (**Area** = (**p** + **q**)/2, where **p** and **q** are the **diagonals**).

The kite has diagonals **p** and **q**, and sides **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d**. 
Because the shape we are dealing with is a rhombus, **a** = **b** = **c** = **d**, and we can simply rename every side **a**.

Here, K finds the area to be [(**a** + **a**)*(**a** + **a**)]/4 = **a**^2.
We know that **a** > 1/2 **p** and **a** > 1/2 **q** (in a triangle, the side opposite the larger angle is greater than the side opposite the smaller angle).

So, **a**^2 > 1/2 **p** * 1/2 **q** = 1/4 (**p** * **q**).
However, the Area of a Kite is 1/2(**p** * **q**). So, this is not helpful.
I tried playing around with things, but couldn't come up with an inequality that would allow me to prove that **K** > **Area of a Rhombus**.

*Side question*: I am assuming **p** and **q** are not necessarily equal, because it seems that websites have treated the diagonals of the Rhombus as being so. But, because the Rhombus is symmetrical by the vertical and horizontal axises, does not **p** necessarily equal **q** in a Rhombus (not a Kite)? If not, why?

---

2. Trapezoid (**Area** = [(**a** + **c**) * **h**]/2, where **a** and **c** are the **bases** and **h** the **height**)

Take a trapezoid with sides **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d**, and assume each side is of a different length than all the others. Because **K** = (**a** + **c**)(**b** + **d**)/4 = [(**a** + **c**)/2] * [(**b** + **d**)/2], I have to show that (**b** + **d**)/2 > **h**, (**b** + **d**) > 2**h**. Because **b** > **h** and **d** > **h**, (**b** + **d**) > 2**h** (in a triangle, the side opposite the larger angle is greater than the side opposite the smaller angle).

---

3. Parallelogram/Rhombus (**Area** = **a** * **h**, where **a** is the **base** and **h** the **height**)

This one, I believe I arrived at an answer. Because a parallelogram with the sides **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d** (where **a** is the top and bottom sides, the basses), has **a** = **c** and **b** =  **d**, **K** = (**a** + **c**)(**b** + **d**)/4 = (2**a**)(2**b**)/4 = **a** * **b**. We know that  **b** >  **h** (in a triangle, the side opposite the larger angle is greater than the side opposite the smaller angle). So, **a** * **b** >  **a** * **h**.

---

Are there any quadrilaterals that I'm not considering?
Was there an easier way to approach this problem (that is, more efficiently/with less work)?

Thank you, in advance, for you time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider an *arbitrary* quadrilateral, not just a few special types.

We can assume the quadrilateral is convex, otherwise the area can be increased without affecting the side lengths.

The $\sin$-based area formula clinches it . . .

Let $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4$ be the interior angles between sides $$a,b\qquad b,c\qquad c,d\qquad d,a$$
respectively.

Draw the diagonal $u$ forming two triangles, one with sides $a,b,u$, and the other with sides $c,d,u$.

Let $k$ denote the area of the quadrilateral.

Then the area of the triangle with sides $a,b,u$ is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta_1$, and the area of the triangle with sides $c,d,u$ is $\frac{1}{2}cd\sin\theta_3$, hence
$$k = \frac{1}{2}(ab\sin\theta_1 + cd\sin\theta_3)$$
Now erase the diagonal $u$ and draw the other diagonal, $v$ say.

Then the area of the triangle with sides $b,c,v$ is $\frac{1}{2}bc\sin\theta_2$, and the area of the triangle with sides $d,a,v$ is $\frac{1}{2}da\sin\theta_4$, hence
$$k = \frac{1}{2}(bc\sin\theta_2 + da\sin\theta_4)$$
Summing the two results for $k$ yields
$$2k = \frac{1}{2}(ab\sin\theta_1 + bc\sin\theta_2 + cd\sin\theta_3+da\sin\theta_4)$$
so
$$k = \frac{1}{4}(ab\sin\theta_1 + bc\sin\theta_2 + cd\sin\theta_3+da\sin\theta_4)$$
But for $\theta \in \{\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4\}$, we have$\;0^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ,\;$hence$\;0 < \sin\theta \le 1,\;$with equality if and only if$\;\theta = 90^\circ$.

It follows that
$$k \le \frac{1}{4}(ab + bc + cd+da)$$
with equality if and only if the quadrilateral is a rectangle.

Now simply note that $ab + bc + cd+da = (a+c)(b+d)$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: "We can assume the quadrilateral is convex, otherwise the area can be increased without affecting the side lengths."

Comment: Draw a non-convex quadrilateral. The two sides whose interior angle exceeds $180$ degrees can be "flipped" to the outside, thus increasing the area. The new quadrilateral is convex, and has the same side lengths as the old one, but a larger area. Since the claimed inequality holds for the new quadrilateral, it holds for the old one as well.